# Oracle Complex query help requireds

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

hi i have a table with following field godwon,productName ,quantity i want to get result
godown and product wise
please check image[image]

Remember godown are not fix its depend on user maybe 2 godowns or maybe 100 godowns

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution depends on the data - do you have only 6 'Godown' values? If so, you can try below solution:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  godown VARCHAR2(20),
  product_name VARCHAR2(20),
  quantity NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown1', 'Rice', 5);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown1', 'Tea', 6);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown1', 'Milk', 4);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown2', 'Rice', 6);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown2', 'Tea', 7);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown2', 'Milk', 5);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown3', 'Rice', 8);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown3', 'Tea', 3);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown3', 'Milk', 5);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown4', 'Rice', 3);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown4', 'Tea', 2);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown4', 'Milk', 1);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown5', 'Rice', 4);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown5', 'Tea', 6);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown5', 'Milk', 7);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown6', 'Rice', 9);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown6', 'Tea', 24);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Godown6', 'Milk', 12);

COMMIT;

SELECT
    product_name,
    godown1_sum_quantity AS Godown1,
    godown2_sum_quantity AS Godown2,
    godown3_sum_quantity AS Godown3,
    godown4_sum_quantity AS Godown4,
    godown5_sum_quantity AS Godown5,
    godown6_sum_quantity AS Godown6,
    (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM my_table WHERE product_name = data.product_name) AS Total
  FROM (
    SELECT
        product_name,
        godown,
        quantity
      FROM my_table
  )
  PIVOT (SUM(quantity) AS sum_quantity
  FOR (godown) IN (
    'Godown1' AS Godown1,
    'Godown2' AS Godown2,
    'Godown3' AS Godown3,
    'Godown4' AS Godown4,
    'Godown5' AS Godown5,
    'Godown6' AS Godown6
    )
  ) data
;
```

Check at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f8e8/1

Comment: no godown not fix godown is user defined maybe only 2 godowns or maybe 100 godowns its depend on user

Comment: @user1153193 Then I guess you'll have to do it the way I proposed here: [Pivot with IN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298424/oracle-pivot-with-subquery/19302540#19302540)

Comment: but i use oracle 10 g xe

Comment: if i fix godown when user add new godown i need to modify my query and add new godown in my query which is not efficient way please guide me how to achieve this

Comment: You'll have to write a stored procedure that PIPEs rows. See the link from my previous comment to get a general idea what a PIPELINED function is and read more on the subject online.

Comment: please explain me more how to achive this with store procedure

Comment: try to search  google still found nothing

Comment: @user1153193 Well my bad then, don't think it's possible then - you have to know how many columns are to be returned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39595/discussion-between-user1153193-and-przemyslaw-kruglej)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE statement with a aggregate function.

```
  SELECT product_name,
         MIN (CASE WHEN godown = 'godown1' THEN quantity END) godown1,
         MIN (CASE WHEN godown = 'godown2' THEN quantity END) godown2,
         MIN (CASE WHEN godown = 'godown3' THEN quantity END) godown3,
         MIN (CASE WHEN godown = 'godown4' THEN quantity END) godown4,
         MIN (CASE WHEN godown = 'godown5' THEN quantity END) godown5,
         MIN (CASE WHEN godown = 'godown6' THEN quantity END) godown6,
         SUM (quantity)
    FROM products
GROUP BY product_name;
```

You can also use PIVOT operators in 11g, but it won't give you the final total column. You'll have to calculate it separately.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT godown, product_name, quantity FROM products) 
        PIVOT (MIN (
                    quantity)
        FOR (godown)
        IN  ('godown1' AS godown1,
            'godown2' AS godown2,
            'godown3' AS godown3,
            'godown4' AS godown4,
            'godown5' AS godown5,
            'godown6' AS godown6));
```

Comment: godown not fix maybe its 2 or maybe 100 its depend on user