# Pivot with subquery results in tablular format

Tags: oracle, pivot

Consider my table structure below,

```
create table test_pivot (
  id number,
  value number
);

insert into test_pivot values(1, 100);
insert into test_pivot values(2, 200);
insert into test_pivot values(3, 300);
insert into test_pivot values(4, 400);
insert into test_pivot values(5, 500);
insert into test_pivot values(6, 600);
```

I can write a PIVOT query to transpose the columns as headers.

```
select *
  from test_pivot pivot(sum(value) as val_ for(id) in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

This will give me an output like the below,

```
1_VAL_  2_VAL_  3_VAL_  4_VAL_  5_VAL_
100     200     300     400     500
```

Now, I dont want to hardcode the values in the pivot clause but I want to use a subquery instead. So I tried this,

```
select *
  from test_pivot pivot XML (sum(value) as val_ for(id) in(select id from test_pivot where id = 2));
```

The result I get when I run this is,

```
<PivotSet><item><column name = "ID">2</column><column name = "VAL_">200</column></item></PivotSet>
```

Since PIVOT in oracle forces us to put XML in the query to use a sub-query, the result is of XML format. Is there any way to convert this result to a tabular format??

Comment: I haven't tried this, but there's a similar question with [a possible way to extract the data from the XML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19302540/266304).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. It uses a function with PIPELINED functionality. I could only wish it was possible thru a query :|