# pivot query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have one requirement to pivot the data. I have tried below query by using pivot:

```
select * from 

(
  select g.geography_code,
       g.description,
       a.external_id_1 as ext
from geography_alignment_timeline gal
join geography g on g.geography_id=gal.geography_id
join alignment a on gal.alignment_id=a.alignment_id
join team t on a.team_id=t.team_id
where g.tenant_id=500104
and   g.region_id=7888500001071037
and   t.team_id=70000012130101
)
pivot
(
  max(ext) for ext in (select external_id_1 from alignment where tenant_id=500104)
);
```

and am getting the error:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression

 Tables and columns: 
     Geography : Geography_id,Geography_code,Description,External_id_1
     Geography_alignment_timeline : Geography_id,Alignment_id,External_id_1
     Alignment : Alignment_id,team_id,Alignment_name,External_id_1
     team : Team_id,name,Description,External_id_1
```

I want to display the data like below..

[image]

each team having separte alignment_ids. i want to display the data like above.

Can you please help me what is the issue?

Comment: We don't have your tables, we don't have your data, how would someone help? Please post a test case.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4 or you could post the full error message. Does the inner query work on it's own?

Comment: YOu cannot have subquery in `IN` clause. It should be [hard coded](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1) values.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pivot dynamically; the number of values (which corresponds to the number of columns in the final result set) need to be known at parse time. It is not valid syntax to use a subquery in the pivot's `IN`  clause. You need to hard-code the values to expect to see.

It is possible to have a dynamic XML pivot but that probably won't help you here; you'd [need to unpack the XML somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19298424/266304). You may also be able [to use dynamic SQL to generate the query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16978047/266304) but a ref cursor result might not be appropriate for you.

Answer (score 0):

read the [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE) document which was related to pivot clause.

as per  my understanding

> A subquery is used only in conjunction with the XML keyword.