# Create Dynamic Pivot - multiple rows into fields based on 2 common fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How can I pivot the PONT_LOC field into separate fields for each value, thus creating one row per SECTION & SURVEY_DATE combination, the number of rows will always very based on SECTION & SURVEY_DATE, can someone please help? Oracle11g

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT STATE_CODE||SHRP_ID AS SECTION, SURVEY_DATE, POINT_LOC
FROM (SELECT * FROM MON_DIS_JPCC_FAULT ORDER BY STATE_CODE, SHRP_ID, SURVEY_DATE, POINT_LOC)
WHERE STATE_CODE=55
AND SHRP_ID LIKE '0213'
AND CRACK_OR_JOINT='J'
AND SURVEY_DATE='04/27/1998');

+---------+-------------+-----------+
| SECTION | SURVEY_DATE | POINT_LOC |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 3.2       |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 7.9       |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 12.5      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 17.1      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 21.7      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 26.2      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 30.7      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 35.2      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 39.8      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 44.4      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 48.9      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 53.5      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 58        |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 62.8      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 67.1      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 71.7      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 76.5      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 81.2      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 85.6      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 90.2      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 94.7      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 99.4      |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 103.9     |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 108.3     |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 114       |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 117.7     |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 122.1     |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 126.7     |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 131.3     |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 136       |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 140.5     |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 144.9     |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 149.4     |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

Here is some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE MON_DIS_JPCC_FAULT
(SECTION VARCHAR(255),
SURVEY_DATE VARCHAR(255),
POINT_LOC DECIMAL(3,1));

INSERT INTO MON_DIS_JPCC_FAULT
VALUES ('550213', '04/27/1998', 3.2);

INSERT INTO MON_DIS_JPCC_FAULT
VALUES ('550213', '04/27/1998', 7.9);

INSERT INTO MON_DIS_JPCC_FAULT
VALUES ('550213', '04/27/1998', 12.5);

INSERT INTO MON_DIS_JPCC_FAULT
VALUES ('550213', '04/27/1998', 17.1);

INSERT INTO MON_DIS_JPCC_FAULT
VALUES ('550213', '04/27/1998', 21.7);
```

I don't know if my explanation is correct...here is a sample of the output I'm looking for:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| SECTION | SURVEY_DATE | POINT_LOC_1 | POINT_LOC_2 | POINT_LOC_3 | POINT_LOC_4 | POINT_LOC_5 |...6, 7, 8, etc...
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 550213  | 04/27/1998  | 3.2         | 7.9         | 12.5        | 17.1        | 21.7        |
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Also, the number of POINT_LOC's is always going to be different.

I hope this makes sense, and any assistance is greatly appreciated!

---

Okay, this is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT STATE_CODE||SHRP_ID AS SECTION, SURVEY_DATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STATE_CODE, SHRP_ID, SURVEY_DATE ORDER BY STATE_CODE, SHRP_ID, SURVEY_DATE, POINT_LOC) AS "JOINT_NO", POINT_LOC
FROM MON_DIS_JPCC_FAULT
WHERE STATE_CODE=55
AND SHRP_ID IN ('0215','0216')
AND CRACK_OR_JOINT='J')

PIVOT (MAX("POINT_LOC") FOR JOINT_NO IN (1,2,3,4,5,34,35,36))

ORDER BY "SECTION", SURVEY_DATE
```

Here is a sample result:

```
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| SECTION | SURVEY_DATE | 1   | 2   | 3    | 4    | 5    | 34    | 35    | 36 |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| 550215  | 04/28/1998  | 3.1 | 7.9 | 12.5 | 17.1 | 21.7 | -     | -     | -  |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| 550215  | 06/08/2000  | 3.1 | 7.9 | 12.5 | 17.1 | 21.7 | -     | -     | -  |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| 550215  | 04/22/2002  | 3.1 | 7.9 | 12.5 | 17.1 | 21.7 | -     | -     | -  |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| 550215  | 08/15/2005  | 3.1 | 7.9 | 12.5 | 17.1 | 21.7 | -     | -     | -  |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| 550215  | 05/12/2010  | 3.1 | 7.9 | 12.5 | 17.1 | 21.7 | -     | -     | -  |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| 550215  | 07/31/2012  | 3.1 | 7.9 | 12.5 | 17.1 | 21.7 | -     | -     | -  |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| 550216  | 04/24/1998  | 3   | 7.5 | 12   | 16.6 | 21.1 | 148   | 152.4 | -  |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| 550216  | 06/06/2000  | 3   | 7.5 | 12   | 16.6 | 21.1 | 148   | 152.4 | -  |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| 550216  | 04/16/2002  | 3   | 7.5 | 12   | 16.6 | 21.1 | 148   | 152.4 | -  |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| 550216  | 08/12/2005  | 3   | 7.5 | 12   | 16.6 | 21.1 | 148   | 152.4 | -  |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| 550216  | 05/05/2010  | 3   | 7.5 | 12   | 16.6 | 21.1 | 152.3 | 152.4 | -  |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
| 550216  | 07/30/2012  | 3   | 7.5 | 12   | 16.6 | 21.1 | 148   | 152.4 | -  |
+---------+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+-------+----+
```

The problem is the number of POINT_LOC's will vary per SECTION, so I need the "IN (1,2,3,4,5,34,35,36)" part of the SQL to determine the number of rows first, and only include those. I have tried to add a subquery but I keep getting a "missing expression" error, PLEASE HELP :-(

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want `POINT_LOC` to be in a single row for each `SECTION & SURVEY_DATE`.

You can use command LISTAGG for this scenario.

```
SELECT SECTION
       , SURVEY_DATE
       , LISTAGG(POINT_LOC) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SECTION) POINT_LOC
  FROM ...
GROUP BY SECTION, SURVEY_DATE;
```

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT**

Approach : String cocatenation

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PVT (
    CUR_PIVOT   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
    V_SQL       VARCHAR2(4000);
    V_ROW       VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN    
    SELECT LISTAGG(RN, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RN)
      INTO V_ROW
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SECTION, SURVEY_DATE ORDER BY SECTION, SURVEY_DATE, POINT_LOC) RN
              FROM MON_DIS_JPCC_FAULT);

    V_SQL := 'SELECT * FROM (' ||
             'SELECT SECTION, SURVEY_DATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SECTION, SURVEY_DATE ORDER BY SECTION, SURVEY_DATE, POINT_LOC) AS JOINT_NO, POINT_LOC FROM MON_DIS_JPCC_FAULT' ||
             ') PIVOT (' ||
             'MAX(POINT_LOC)' ||
             'FOR JOINT_NO IN (' || V_ROW || '))';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_SQL);

    OPEN CUR_PIVOT FOR V_SQL;
END PVT;
```

You can call then obtain the result by:

```
VARIABLE DT REFCURSOR;
EXEC PVT(:X);
PRINT X;
```

However, there are limitations on string length.

Comment: LISTAGG will just give POINT_LOC in one field, I was looking to get the values in separate fields. Please help :-)

Comment: Not sure what you want to do with the data. But to achieve your goals, you can look into **PIVOT**. However, PIVOT is not dynamic, it need a specific list of data set. For dynamic, can look into **PIVOT XML**.

Comment: I tried to use PIVOT XML, but couldn't figure out how to get exactly what I require. Can you please look at my updates above and make and suggestions/examples? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For `PIVOT XML`, you will have to format the context, you can see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19302540/2163646 . However, you still need to know ahead number of columns you will have. Another approach is to use `string concatenation`. My view, if your data is to be further processed in Excel, `LISTAGG` will be a faster approach, you can easily format the data by TAB character. Good Luck..